# Как установить пустое поле по умолчанию в выпадающем списке, по умолчанию выбирается первая страна

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Помогите сделать чтобы по умолчанию при загрузке страницы была выбрана пустая строка, а не первая Страна..

```
<p class="form-row">
        <label for="country" class="dealer-form__label">Country</label>
        <select name="country" id="country" >
            <?php foreach ($countries as $code => $country_name) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $code ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $country_name ); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Помогите сделать чтобы по умолчанию при загрузке страницы была выбрана
> пустая строка, а не первая

```
<p class="form-row">
            <label for="country" class="dealer-form__label">Country</label>
            <select name="country" id="country" >
             <option disabled selected value> -- select the country-- </option>
                <?php foreach ($countries as $code => $country_name) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $code ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $country_name ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: Всё работает! Благодарю!